# try: VAR = ... except: VAR = ... finally: VAR - Local variable 'VAR' might be referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pycharm

Why is `PyCharm` warning me that `streamer` might be referenced before assignment? In my opinion, all the situations are covered by `try` or `except` block so in `finally` block the `streamer` is always defined.

```
    try:
        streamer = Streamer.objects.get(user_id=self.user_id)
    except Streamer.DoesNotExist:
        streamer = Streamer.objects.create(**streamer_attrs)
    except:
        streamer = Streamer.objects.create(**streamer_attrs)
    finally:
        for fieldname, value in streamer_attrs:
            setattr(streamer, fieldname, value)
```

[image]

Is there a reason behind this warning?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you don't need both `except` clauses here, since the second one includes the first, and both have the same statement in them. And you should not use bare `except` but rather `except Exception` to avoid catching exceptions like `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the assignment in your `except` section throws an exception as well (and it may):

```
except:
    streamer = Streamer.objects.create(**streamer_attrs)
```

.. then the `finally` block still gets executed, but `streamer` won't be defined. I think the issue is you didn't realise that a `finally` gets executed even when an exception occurs?

The only times a `finally` won't run is if the thread or process that has the block is killed beforehand, you exited the program (using `exit()`) or something underlying fails (like the OS, VM, container, etc.)